# Maxima and Minima of $x+\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

$$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}\\ \therefore f^{'}(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}\\
\text{now, } f^{'}(x)=0\ \Rightarrow x=+1,-1\\
f^{"}(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}\\f^{"}(1)>0\ \&\ f^{"}(-1)<0\\
\max f(x)=-2<\min f(x)=2$$
So, the funtion has maxima and minima respectively at $x=-1$ and $x=1$

But, function has far more value than the maxima and far less value than the minima. Moreover, minima is larger than maxima. I am confused. Thanking You.

Comment: Hint: Look at a plot of the function. Hint2: the criteria you applied to find the extremal points only gives you **local** minima and maxima.

Comment: f(-1) and f(1), like the others have mentioned, are local extrema, not global or absolute extrema, which may be what you are thinking of. Absolute maximum would be the largest value a function takes across its domain, and absolute minimum would be the smallest.

Comment: You can also use AM>GM to find minimum value, which is 2. (that only works on the assumption that x is not zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure of finding stationary point and verifying the second gradient only promises local optimality.

As we can see from the graph, $(1,2)$ indeed is a local minimum and $(-1,-2)$ is indeed a local maxima.

[image]

They are only smallest or largest in a confined region.

The shortest person in a group can be taller than the tallest person in another group.

Comment: Thanks. By the procedure I was doing, it is giving local maxima and local minima of two different branches of the graph of the function.